# How do I get a users input and set it as a variable?

Tags: discord.js

I am very new to Discord.js so please forgive me for any basic errors.

I am trying to create a command that will ask for a name, and then store the users input into a variable, however this is proving itself quite difficult.

After the program sends the message "What would you like to name your event?", I type "TEST", and then it sends another message saying "createevent", the command word.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith('createevent')) {
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        
        message.channel.startTyping()
        await sleep(500);
        message.channel.stopTyping()
        
        message.lineReply('What would you like to name your event?')
        
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 50000}).then(collected => {
            const eventname = message.content;
            message.channel.send(eventname);
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should stop the collector and, as you said you want to know the content that the user replies, the content in your case would be `collected.content` not `message.content`.

Comment: `collected` will be a Collection<string, message>, you will want to grab the first entry: `collected.first().content`

Comment: Oh, i forgot he's using awaitMessages, So Yeah it would be collected.first().content